# Is there a way to reduce the number of yields in an infinite generator communicating with its caller?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-generator

At a discussion about Javascript generators someone cooked up an interesting function:

```
function *foo() {
    var y = 1;
    while(true) yield (y = (y * (yield)));
}
```

Now, this function can be used via:

```
var results = [];
var bar = foo();
bar.next();
results.push(bar.next(2));
bar.next();
results.push(bar.next(2));
bar.next();
results.push(bar.next(2));
bar.next();
results.push(bar.next(2));
```

As we can see, in order to get the next product we need to call `next` twice. The question is: can this somehow be resolved with a single yield?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  while(true) y *=  yield y;
```

Just yield y and then multiply y with its result.

```js
function *foo() {
    let y = 1;
    while(true) y *=  yield y;
}

const bar = foo();
bar.next();
console.log(bar.next(2).value);
console.log(bar.next(2).value);
console.log(bar.next(2).value);
```

Comment: *Just* simplified mine to the same thing. Great minds, though your mind was apparently faster. :-)

Comment: @NinaScholz - What do you mean by "take 1 as first value"? Once you've primed the generator (which you need to do in order to pass it things -- but perhaps that's the call you mean), this returns 2, then 4, then 8, just like the calls to the generator in the question that the OP is pushing to `results`. One could modify it to accept the initial `y` in the `foo` call.

Comment: i mean the empty call for moving the first value into the iterator and getting at the same time this first value back ... do i miss something?